# How to edit pixel values of color image in SageMath?

Tags: image, rgb, pixel, sage

I would like to change pixel values in a color [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zyRvIUc1I9rC-NrU4SYjdbbPf8NOrQk0/view?usp=sharing) with Sagemath. I can do the same in python, but my program contains some parts which can not be done with python.  Here are the codes for SageMath:

**MWE:**

```
from PIL import Image
img=Image.open('image.pgm')
pxl=img.load()
#pxls=img.getdata()
print pxl[0,0]
```

When I compile thse codes with sage, error occurs :

```
"  File "smmm.sage.py", line 8, in <module>
    print pxl[_sage_const_0 ,_sage_const_0 ]
TypeError: an integer is required
"
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide an example with an image we can try out that would be ideal.  However, I suspect that if you do

```
print pxl[int(0),int(0)]
```

you might be in good shape.  The issue is that `pxl` might require Python ints, not Sage Integers.